# tiny mce Uncaught TypeError: ht is not a constructor and insert edit link not working

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I would appreciate some suggestions of how I can correct the following behaviour in TinyMCE.  When I click on the "Bullet List" or "Numbered List" button I get Uncaught TypeError: e.replace is not a function, and when I click on "Insert/edit Link" or "Insert/edit Image" I get  Uncaught TypeError: ht is not a constructor and nothing happens. I have appended the call trace for this second error below.

I have installed TinyMCE 6.4.2 - 2023-04-26 on my web server and this presents the following editor to FireFox 115.0.2 browser or Chromium Version 115.0.5790.110 (Official Build) snap (64-bit).

[image]

Note that I have defined:

```
var tinyMCEparms = {
    selector            : 'textarea',
    plugins             : 'link lists image',
    menubar             : false,
    language            : 'en',
    skin                : 'oxide-dark',
    toolbar             : "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | bullist numlist | link image",
    height              : "170px",
    content_css         : "/styles.css"
};
```

When I click on the "Insert/Edit Link" button in the header line of this TinyMce editor I get the following error, and the function is not performed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ht is not a constructor
bt http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js:9
At http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js:9
Pt http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js:9
Dt http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js:9
buttonBehaviours http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
wy http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
buttonBehaviours http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
run http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
L http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
run http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
r http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
k http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Lw http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
fold http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Lw http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Pw http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Uw http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
triggerEvent http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Si http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Si http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
triggerEvent http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Vs http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Fs http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Rs http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
e http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
r http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
k http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Lw http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
fold http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Lw http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Pw http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Uw http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
triggerEvent http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
triggerEvent http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Si http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Si http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
triggerEvent http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
r http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
s http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Fo http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
tc http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
tc http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
r http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
H http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Vw http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
Gw http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
v http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
renderUI http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
renderUI http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js:4
t http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4
t http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4
vA http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4
o http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4
promise callback*xA http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4
render http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4
render http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4
s http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4
s http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4
Re http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4
s http://localhost/jscripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4
...
```